# upper limit on concurrent editing?

Tags: performance

I am about to install a multi-site wordpress and was wondering if there is a big performance degradation if there are multiple concurrent editors using the system at the same time, or what the average safe number of them would be? I am not talking about editing the same record, just editing separate records at the same time. I had a previous wordpress site that would always slow down significantly when there were multiple admins/editors logged in at the same time...

Does anyone have any experience with this, resources they could point me to, or some table of average acceptable loads (say on a shared or dedicated server)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most of editing process (from loading editor page to saving post) happens in browser and doesn't involve server.

The one exceptions is auto save feature - post will be quietly saved by JavaScript in background, every minute by default. This might cause performance issue if you have considerably large posts, considerably many editors and poorly performing database.

Auto-save interval can be customized by [defining `AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL` constant in `wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Modify_AutoSave_Interval).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like that. 5 backend users opening a single dashboard page is equivalent to you refreshing (Ctrl + F5) that page 5 times. Its just the load, WP dashboard is a bit heavy but that is totally based on how much your webhost can handle.

So in short, in general, loading a WP dashboard page is heavy than a front end page and several users using the dashboard at once, increases the load on the server a bit and you will experience slowness if your webhost is crawling at that load.